# How to make this query on mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Here is my collection structure...

```
   {
       "_id": ObjectId("5316f53228551c0af600019b"),
       "age_range": {
         "min": NumberInt(21)
      },
 "likes": {
     "data": {
       "0": {
         "category": "Tv show",
         "name": "Those Who Kill on A&E",
         "created_time": "2014-03-03T15:08:02+0000",
         "id": "629689387051864"
      },
       "1": {
         "category": "Journalist",
         "name": "Robin Roberts",
         "created_time": "2014-02-24T18:02:43+0000",
         "id": "780950061932847"
      }
},
{
 "_id": ObjectId("5316f53228551c0af600019b"),
`
```

I need to fetch total number of users likes for each category. 
For example

```
Category Name: Journalist
Total users: 10
```

Comment: This is the one i tried but its not working for me `db.facebook_data.group( {
                   key: {'likes.data.category': 1 },
                   reduce: function ( curr, result ) {
                               result.total += curr.item.qty;
                           },
                   initial: { total : 0 }
                } )`

Comment: Perhaps try aggregation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Comment: If the `data` property values were structured as an array and not as properties, this would be trivial to do with aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

try this (collection should be the collection that you have)

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    for (a in this.likes.data){
        var name = this.likes.data[a].category;
        emit(name, 1);
    }
}
var reduceFunction = function(key, val){
    return Array.sum(val);
}
db.collection.mapReduce(mapFunction, reduceFunction, {out: "myresult"});
db.myresult.find();
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. I have implemented you query format but it returns empty result set

Comment: try it  in the mongo console first and see if there are any results.